# Is it possible to use multiprocessing.Queue to communicate between TWO python scripts?

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, interprocess

I have just learned about python concurrency and its library module multiprocessing. Most examples I have encountered are within ONE python script, it spawns several processes, and communicate among them using multiprocessing.Queue.

My question is: without using message broker or a third supervising application, can TWO python script communicate with each other using multiprocessing.Queue?

Comment: I can't grasp what exactly you are asking, perhaps you could add some pseudo-code or real code explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are maybe looking for something like `RabbitMQ` or equivalent solution

Comment: @Arount But then it is an message broker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` module is a package that supports **spawning** processes, so that you can write code that executes in parallel. This means that you can write one python script that spawns multiple processes transparently, without worrying much about how these processes serialize data & pass it to each-other.

As for your question, it depends... Why do they need to be separate?

- If the only concern is that your functions are defined in different modules/scripts, you can just import everything you need in the script that uses the `Queue` and make all your functions available in one script.
- If your use-case is that you want one script to wait for requests (server) & the other script to be a client (it sends requests to the server when needed and waits for response), then you need to implement some sort of RPC protocol.

You can make an http server using web frameworks like Flask & send http requests to it from the client, or if you only need to share short simple messages, you can implement your own message exchange protocol using [sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).

So to sum up: It is possible for 2 python processes to communicate without a message broker (e.g: through sockets). But you want to use `multiprocessing` if you want to run 1 python script that spawns multiple processes that can communicate with one-another. If instead you need to start 2 independent scripts and have one of them request the other one to do some work & return the output, you need to implement some RPC protocol between them. The `multiprocessing.Queue` object itself is not a replacement for message brokers. If you want independent scripts that are started independently to communicate through a message queue, that queue needs to live either in one of the processes that are communicating (i.e: the server), or in a 3rd process.

Comment: Very detailed. Thumbs up

Comment: @tomas would this type of mechanism be relevant if we had 2 separate python processes, one using python2 and one using 3?